# I can't get text on the right of image in CSS after following a tutorial

Tags: css, text

I was following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwYbpRQHZRk on how to place text beside an image without using float. I did everything in the tutorial and my text still won't go beside the image. I tried modifying the width, padding and margins, but I still don't know what's wrong.

[image: This was the result for me compared to the video]

```css
.MainBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: flex;
  transition: .5s;
}

.MainBox:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.MainBox .imgBox {
  width: 150px;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}

.MainBox .imgBox img {
  max-width: 70%;
}

.MainBox .Content {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.MainBox .Content h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: #e69411;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.MainBox .Content p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0 0;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainBox">
  <div class="imgBox">
    <img src="planeswalker.jpg">
    <div class="Content">
      <h2>My Article title here</h2>
      <p>adadsasdasalsjdhlasdlaksdlaskdhaloskdlasdhlaksdhl dkjalsdjlaskdjalksdjlaksjdlaksdjlaksdjlasdjlaksdjlad lkasdjlaksdjlaksdjalskdjalskdjalskdjalksdjalksdlskdd jhgaofkiafhjgaudfhgnvuajfnapfjudgnapujnvpudfjnvpafuj nvoafvnaopjfnvapodfjvnapofjnvaponjvfapojnvapofvnapvp
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had my div class="Content" in the div class="imgBox" by mistake. So now it looks like this:

```
<div class="MainBox">
    <div class="imgBox">
        <img src="planeswalker.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="Content">
        <h2>My Article title here</h2>
        <p>adadsasdasalsjdhlasdlaksdlaskdhaloskdlasdhlaksdhl
        dkjalsdjlaskdjalksdjlaksjdlaksdjlaksdjlasdjlaksdjlad
        lkasdjlaksdjlaksdjalskdjalskdjalskdjalksdjalksdlskdd
        jhgaofkiafhjgaudfhgnvuajfnapfjudgnapujnvpudfjnvpafuj
        nvoafvnaopjfnvapodfjvnapofjnvaponjvfapojnvapofvnapvp</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you ShamSandwiches for helping me think outside the box! :)

Answer (score 0):

img src="planeswalker.jpg" may have to go inside the div class="Content" and then try align everything in that div to the left. Hopefully this helps, I think the problem is that you have added the image onto the html directly and it's not being altered/position by any css at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, It helped me see something that I never even noticed.